# Hover effects div position and borders

Tags: html, hover, css

I want to change a couple things on a div when I hover over it.

I would like to make the box shadow bigger and move the div very slightly up and to the left, while not affecting other divs surrounding this div. Here is my code so far.

```
#divshadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-right:  3%;
    padding-top: 8px
}

.divshadow:hover {
}
```

```
<div id="divshadow" class="divshadow"
    style="float:left;width:30%; margin-left:2%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using CSS3 transitions. Values on `#divshadow:hover` would need to be adjusted to your needs.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de3Qv/1/)

```
#divshadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-right:3%;
    padding-top:8px;

    transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#divshadow:hover {
    top:-3px;
    left:-3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888;
}
```

Comment: that's amazing! Thank you so much.  The only issue is that in ie it moves twice so it looks choppy.  It's not one smooth movement but two movements.

Comment: i fixed that by replacing the .5s with 0s

Comment: In a good browser the transition should be perfectly smooth. Set the time as how long you want the transition to take, it should happen instantly with 0s effectively removing the need for a transition at all :)